# How to select multiple wordpress item (woocommerce order) from multiple paginated page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce order list has 50 orders per page. How can I select multiple orders from different pages.

Let's say I have 500 order list, by default Woocommerce paginate these  order into 10 pages (50 order/page). I need to select order no 5, 150 and 400 (they aren't in a single page) to run bulk action like export. How can I achieve that?

One approach I am trying is to enter comma separated order number into the search field and then just select the result.

Is there any quick and better way to do that?